# Java Using String[] args as input, how can you retrieve its contents?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

In a homework assignment we are supposed to retrieve an input file by clicking on Eclipse's Run Configurations item, then clicking Arguments tab and typing in a file name. I can do that, but then when I try to `forLoop{ SOP(args[i] }` it just prints out the name of the file.

Then I try `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(args)` and it says I cannot do that either.

How can you use the Arguments tab to load a file and then retrieve its contents using a Scanner?

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(args[i]);
}
```

The above code just prints: Filename.txt

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(args);
```

Gives me an error.

Comment: Can you edit your actual code into your question so we can more easily see what you're doing wrong/what you're misunderstanding?

Comment: I put the code there, the only other step is using Eclipses dropdowns to make args refer to the Filename.txt

Comment: it's an array. So args[0] etc.

Comment: When you put the filename in the arguments section of your IDE, all it's going to pass to Java is a string of the filename, not the file itself (this is why your `for` loop only prints the file's name). You have to open the file yourself. This is very common in any programming language.

Comment: Try: `Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));` if you want to read the file specified by the first argument.

Comment: What you're missing, basically, is the documentation. Here's the Scanner documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), which contains all its constructors, and explain what they do. What you're also missing is the fact that error messages are intended to be read, because they explain what's wrong. Just saying "I get an error" shows that you didn't read the error message, or considered it was meaningless. It's not. Read error messages carefully, and post them when you don't understand them and want us to explain the problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanner does not provide a constructor which takes an array as an argument. It provides a constructor which takes a single String (containing the data to scan), though.

In case you want to scan a file (that's what it seems judging from your `System.out`), just pass a file argument to Scanner's constructor, as shown below.

Change it from:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(args);
```

to:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new java.io.File(args[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That was what I needed. Will accept it when it lets me.

Comment: @phyremynd Note that passing a plain `String` to a `Scanner` constructor will *not* treat the `String` as the name of a file. The `Scanner` will just use the `String` itself as the data to scan through. Just wanted to make sure that was clear. The second line of code will open the actual file for you, as you want.